# How to properly redirect a Webview that contains a pdf to Google Drive

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

On an Xamarian.Forms app, which is trying to redirect links that contain a PDF in from a WebView to a Google Drive URL. My code works as expected on iOS but just spins on an Android.

```
public partial class Balance : ContentPage
{
    public Balance()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        website.Navigated += WebView_Navigated;
        website.Navigating += WebView_Navigating;
        UrlWebViewSource source = new UrlWebViewSource();
        source.Url = "https://www.google.com";
        website.Source = source;
    }

    private void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        progress.IsVisible = true;
        website.IsVisible = false;
    }

    public void WebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        progress.IsVisible = false;
        website.IsVisible = true;
        if (e.Url.Contains("pdf") && !e.Url.Contains("drive.google.com"))
        {
            var webview = (WebView)sender;
            website.Source = "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + e.Url;
        }
    }
}
```

On Android the site never loads and the activity indicator just sits and spins.

Comment: website.Source = https://docs.google.com/gview?
    embedded=true&url="+e.Url;

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I use your code and redirect a webview, here is my code, there is no issue on android, nospins on android :

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView
            x:Name="website"
            HeightRequest="1000"
            Navigated="Website_Navigated"
            Navigating="Website_Navigating"
            WidthRequest="1000" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>


public partial class Page19 : ContentPage
{
    public Page19 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        UrlWebViewSource source = new UrlWebViewSource();
        //source.Url = "https://www.google.com";
        source.Url = "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf";
        website.Source = source;
    }

    private void Website_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {

        website.IsVisible = false;
    }

    private void Website_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {

        website.IsVisible = true;
        if (e.Url.Contains("pdf") && !e.Url.Contains("drive.google.com"))
        {
            var webview = (WebView)sender;
            website.Source = "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + e.Url;
        }
    }
}
```